# How do I get sentiment from a certain "perspective" or point-of-view?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, sentiment-analysis

Consider the following text

> The verdict is out, the jury has held MS guilty of infringements and
>   levied penalties aggregating to $1.50Bn. It will be a massive blow to
>   the reputation of MS. The defendants, NK, on the other hand were
>   elated. It was an important verdict for them to win. The brokerage
>   group has already upgraded their stock to BUY.

How can I model the problem of inferring the sentiment from perspectives of both the parties, that is, (positive) NK and (negative) MS.

I do not even know what to search for over the internet to, at least, get some start.